# Redirect to controller action from custom IHttpHandler

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, ihttphandler

I have an application in which users need to be able to upload large files (several gigabytes).

To allow for this, I have implemented a custom `IHttpHandler` and it seems to be working fine. However, I would like to redirect the user to a controller action once the custom `IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest()` has completed the file upload. Moreover, I need this redirection to happen in a way that will include all of the original request parameters.

This is my attempt:

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var isUploadReuqest = context.Request.Files.Count > 0;

        if (isUploadReuqest)
        {
            // snip

            context.Response.RedirectToRoute("Default", new { controller = "Home", action = "Upload" });
        }
    }
```

However, my attempt produces the following error:

> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /Home/Upload

This is my RouteConfig:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{controller}/FileUpload");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Note that my customized HTTP handler is located at path `*/FileUpload`. And yes, if you are wondering whether there is an action called `Upload` in the `HomeController`, there is :)

Thanks in advance for any replies!

Comment: You need to write this code only .

 context.Response.RedirectToRoute("Default");

Comment: that will redirect to home index, not to home upload

Comment: As mentioned above, that will redirect to the Index action and not the Upload action as is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further research I realized that I am attempting to redirect to a `HttpPost` action. Apparently that is not possible as a redirect by design is a GET request. I will need to think differently to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Look like your virtual directory name is missing in redirect url. You can try the following code

```
context.Response.Redirect("Home/Upload");
```

or

```
context.Response.Redirect(Url.RouteUrl(new{ controller="Home", action="Upload"}));
```

Here 'Url' is the resemble UrlHelper of MVC

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately neither of these are working. The first suggestion produces the exact same HTTP 404 error. The second suggestion causes an exception: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: routeCollection.